# Isolation level serializable not working as expected?

Tags: postgresql, transaction, isolation-level

I have this table

```
create table testing(
c1 text,
c2 text);
```

I open two transactions simultaneously. `t0 t1..` denote series of time snapshots in increasing order
Transaction 1

```
BEGIN; -- t0
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; -- t2
SELECT * FROM testing where c2 = 'rand'; -- t4
INSERT INTO testing VALUES ('rand', 'xyz'); -- t6
COMMIT; -- t8
```

Transaction 2

```
BEGIN; -- t1
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; -- t3
SELECT * FROM testing where c1 = 'rand1'; -- t5
INSERT INTO testing VALUES ('rand1', 'abc'); -- t7
COMMIT; -- t9
```

After `t9` I get this error 

`ERROR:  could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
DETAIL:  Reason code: Canceled on identification as a pivot, during commit attempt.
HINT:  The transaction might succeed if retried.`

But if you see the statements, they are operating on difference values `rand` and `rand1`. It doesn't make sense for this error to be thrown as they can never end up in a bad state.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Does this change if you make `c1` the primary key?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Will give it a try

Answer (score 5):

Your understanding is fundamentally correct. What you didn't realize is that there can be false positive results when with the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level.

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE) says:

> While PostgreSQL's Serializable transaction isolation level only allows concurrent transactions to commit if it can prove there is a serial order of execution that would produce the same effect, it doesn't always prevent errors from being raised that would not occur in true serial execution.

In this particular case, I would assume that the problem is that you don't have an index on `c1` and `c2` or PostgreSQL chooses to do a sequential scan anyway. As you can read further down on the same page:

> - A sequential scan will always necessitate a relation-level predicate lock. This can result in an increased rate of serialization failures.