# Serializable isolation fails even for unrelated rows

Tags: postgresql, transaction, isolation-level

I have this table

```
create table "tasks" (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, user_id int REFERNCES "user"(id), title TEXT);
```

I also created index on `"tasks"(user_id)`

Then I open two transactions simultaneously. t0 t1.. denote series of time snapshots in increasing order

Transaction 1

```
begin; --T0
set transaction isolation level serializable; --T2
select * from "tasks" where user_id=1; --T4
insert into "tasks" (user_id, title, content, created_time) VALUES (1, 'abc'); --T6
end; --T8
```

Transaction 2

```
begin; --T1
set transaction isolation level serializable; --T3
select * from "tasks" where user_id=2; --T5
insert into "tasks" (user_id, title, content, created_time) VALUES (2, 'abc'); --T7
end; --T9
```

Transactions 1 succeeds but transaction 2 fails. But if i change the `where user_id=?` of the select statements to `where id=?`, it works.

So does SSI allow only unrelated primary key changes and still fails with unrelated indexed columns?

The situation is similar to this question [Isolation level serializable not working as expected?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/242035/isolation-level-serializable-not-working-as-expected). But I have created an index on my column.

Comment: Even if you have an index, it still doesn't guarantee against false positive failures.

Comment: But why does the primary key still work?

Comment: Please share `EXPLAIN` output for the `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out I needed to create more data for my test table, otherwise postgres will opt to use sequential scan instead of index scan and thus causes conflict.